# How SpringBoot @ConditionalOnClass work?

Tags: spring-boot

For example, HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration is annotated with @ConditionalOnClass(CharacterEncodingFilter.class).

What I know about @ConditionalOnClass is to promise the CharacterEncodingFilter in classpath, but if the class not in classpath how could it get through at compile or class loading time.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc on `ConditionalOnClass.value` gives the answer:

> The classes that must be present. Since this annotation is parsed by
>   loading class bytecode, it is safe to specify classes here that may
>   ultimately not be on the classpath, only if this annotation is
>   directly on the affected component and not if this annotation is used
>   as a composed, meta-annotation. In order to use this annotation as a
>   meta-annotation, only use the name attribute.

Also at compile time you do have to have such classes on the classpath to use the `value` attribute of `ConditionalOnClass`.

Spring-boot uses optional dependencies to achieve this. In maven this looks like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
  <artifactId>transactions-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.4</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

In gradle you usually use [compileOnly](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-compile-only-dependencies) to achieve this.